# Using Sum IIF within placeholder expression

Tags: reporting-services

I have the following expression as a placeholder within a textbox which gives me an error of Too many arguments,  what can I do to change this please so that I can count the number of current interviews in dataset 1?
Probably very easy to figure but I've now been looking at it too long!

`="<b>" & "Current Interviews" & "</b>" & vbcrlf & Sum(IIF(Fields!Count.Value, "DataSet1" = "Current",1,0))`

Answer (score 0):

I can't test at the moment but I think it should be

```
="<b>" & "Current Interviews" & "</b>" & vbcrlf & Sum(IIF(Fields!Count.Value = "Current",1,0), "DataSet1")
```

The scope expression (`"DataSet1"`)should be the last argument in the `SUM()`

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try